# Iterating through a list of strings and appending a json returned element for each term in the list

Tags: python, json

<strike>Warning this is very very complex.</strike> (I'm an idiot and should probably take a break), Its a confusing title but I'll do my best to explain what I'm running into,

I have this code:

```
test_terms = ['spartan', 'forerunner', 'didact']

test_list = []

for term in test_terms:

    search_term = term
    search_service = PyMsCognitiveWebSearch('API_Key', search_term,
                                        custom_params={'title': 'name', 'domain': 'url', 'mkt': 'en-usa', 'description': 'url'})
    result = search_service.search(limit=3, format='json')
    test_list.append(result[term].json)

print(test_list)
```

This works when its outside of the loop and I run simply this:

```
search_term = 'spartan'
search_service = PyMsCognitiveWebSearch('API_Key', search_term,
                                        custom_params={'title': 'name', 'domain': 'url', 'mkt': 'en-usa',
                                                       'description': 'url'})
result = search_service.search(limit=3, format='json')
test_list.append(result[0].json)
print(test_list)
```

which gives me:

```
[{'id': 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0', 'name': 'Obstacle Course Races | Spartan Race', 'url': 'https://www.spartan.com/', 'isFamilyFriendly': True, 'displayUrl': 'https://www.spartan.com', 'snippet': 'Spartan Race is the global leader in obstacle course races, with the right challenge for anyone - from first-time racers to elite athletes.', 'deepLinks': ... etc, for three more results}]
```

My first instinct wast to do simply `for term in range(len(test_terms)):`, however this returned a result but instead of the items in the list, I got information on the number 1 through 3.

Next I tried `for item, term enumerate(test_terms):`

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Which makes sense, however I'm not sure exactly how to proceed given that the index is a "string" and I've tried enumerating it in two different ways, removing `result[term].json` and changing it to `result.json` throws an object error too.

Any help would be great! Also the [package](https://github.com/tristantao/py-ms-cognitive/blob/master/README.md) specs if it helps.

UPDATE:

`result` is a web object that is essentially this (via the documentation):

```
packaged_results = [WebResult(single_result_json) for single_result_json in json_results.get("webPages", {}).get("value", [])]
```

[Link the source code](https://github.com/tristantao/py-ms-cognitive/blob/master/py_ms_cognitive/py_ms_cognitive_search/py_ms_cognitive_web_search.py)

But its a giant nested list, I wrote it out on a white board, it returns 3 lists consisting of 9 elements, of mixed types, one list and one dictionary. Literally my nightmare.

Comment: Have you tried ```for term in test_terms:```?

Comment: Yes, that was my first try.

Comment: What's `result[term].json` supposed to *be*? Why don't you use `result[0].json`, like the working version of your code does?

Comment: @Aran-Fey That would just return the 0th element of the query, ideally it should be 0, 1, 2 with each one being a separate object of type `<py_ms_cognitive.py_ms_cognitive_search.py_ms_cognitive_web_search.WebResult object at 'redacted this part'>` that would skip the other two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using 'term' in your for loop makes 'term' a string (one of ['spartan', 'forerunner', 'didact']). You're looking for an integer to use in "result[term]", so, stick with enumerate, but remember using enumerate the first part of the tuple is the "enumeration" and the second part is the item.

```
for i, term in enumerate(test_terms):
    ...
    test_list.append(result[i].json)
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, and should probably step away from the computer for a while. Thank you!